# Flux of a vector field through a surface S.

Tags: calculus

Compute the flux of the vector field $\vec F = 8 x^2y^2z\vec k$ through the surface $S$ which is the cone $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=z$, with $0\le z\le R$, oriented downward.

All I need for this question is $d\vec A$. I thought $d\vec A$ would be $<rcos(\theta), rsin(\theta), -r>$ ($-r$ since it's oriented downward) but that's wrong. I know it's a vector but I'm not sure what to put for it.

Comment: That's correct. Parametrization for the surface is $c(\theta, r) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin\theta, r)$ and $c_{\theta} \times c_{r} = (r \cos \theta, r \sin\theta, - r)$. Now do the dot product with the vector field and integrate over $0 \leq r \leq R, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Comment: @MathLover I actually already have the answer to this question however it also asks for what dA is, and it says it's wrong when I try to enter the answer I mentioned in the original post.